# Query rows between dates and before

Tags: sql, date, sql-server-2012

I have following table:

```
create table MyTable (
    Id int Primary Key Identity,
    UserId int not null,
    StartUnixTime int not null,
    StopUnixTime int not null
)
```

I need to query all rows between a start and end time, plus the row with the highest StartUnixTime (for each UserId) that is smaller then the given start date for multiple UserIds.

Currentyl I'm doing it this way:

```
select
    *
from MyTable
where UserId in (select Id from @users)
and (StartUnixTime between @start and @end)

union all

select
    *
from MyTable
where UserId in (select Id from @users)
and StartUnixTime < @start
and StartUnixTime in (
    select
        max(StartUnixTime)
    from MyTable as mt
    where mt.UserId in (select Id from @users)
    and mt.StartUnixTime < @start
    group by mt.UserId
)
```

Is there a more performant way to do this query? Maybe without the union?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joining on the @users table variable and using "row_number() where = 1" should be faster for selecting the top record per UserId...

```
select
    t.Id,
    t.UserId,
    t.StartUnixTime,
    t.StopUnixTime
from MyTable t inner join @users u on t.UserId = u.Id
where t.StartUnixTime between @start and @end

union all

select
    Id,
    UserId,
    StartUnixTime,
    StopUnixTime
from (
    select
        t.*,
        topStart = row_number() over(partition by t.UserId order by t.StartUnixTime desc)
    from MyTable t inner join @users u on t.UserId = u.Id
    where t.StartUnixTime < @start
) tt
where
    topStart = 1
```

Comment: thanks, i will try that tomorrow and report back to you